# NestJS TCP microservice exception handling - Empty Pipe Object, Server Not Catching Exception Object

Tags: nestjs, microservices, rpc, nestjs-exception-filters

I have Two nestjs project for TCP based microservice, first is projectone which is main server or gateway for microservices. Second is projectwo which is first microservice or client. When i call a service from main server to access the data from client, the dto file throws an bad exception error, which is okay, dto file is working well in client/microservice.

But the issue is that main server or project one is not catching the error thrown by the client/microservice. it return empty error object and throws 500 internal server everytime, not matter which error is thrown by the client/microservice. here is the piece of code.

**Projectone**:

*/app.controller.ts*

```
  async createUser(@Body() data: object): Promise<object> {
    return this.appService.createNewUser(data);
  }
```

*/app.service.ts*

```
@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  public readonly client: ClientProxy;

  constructor() {
    this.client = ClientProxyFactory.create({
      transport: Transport.TCP,
      options: {
        port: 5001,
      },
    });
  }

  async createNewUser(data: any): Promise<any> {
    return this.client.send<any>('user', data).pipe(catchError(error => throwError(() => {
      console.log(error);
      // return new HttpException(error.response, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    })));
  }
}
```

**(Return empty error object)**

*main.ts*

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
  app.useGlobalInterceptors(new ClassSerializerInterceptor(app.get(Reflector)));

  await app.listen(5000);
```

**Projectwo:**

*app.controller.ts*

```
@MessagePattern('user')
  @UseFilters(HttpExceptionFilter)
  async create(@Payload() createUserDto: CreateUserDto): Promise<usermain> {
    console.log('Reaching....');
    return await this.usersService.createUser(createUserDto);
  }
```

*app.service.ts*

```
public async createUser(data: CreateUserDto): Promise<usermain> {
    console.log('Data~~~~~>', data);
    const result = await this.prisma.usermain.create({
      data,
    });
    return result;
  }
```

*exception-filter.ts*

```
@Catch(HttpException)
export class HttpExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
    catch(exception: HttpException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
        const context = host.switchToHttp();
        const response = context.getResponse<Response>();
        const request = context.getRequest<Request>();
        const status = exception.getStatus();

        console.log("EXCEPTION OBJECT-----> ", exception.getStatus());

        response
            .status(status)
            .json({
                statusCode: status,
                timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
                path: request.url,
                message: exception.message
            });
    }
}
```

**how can i catch error object by client/microservice in main server project?**